# Arithmetic progression of four square number with the same common difference

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

I want to know, if is possible found the arithmetic progression of four square number, with the same common difference.

\begin{align}
\ & a^2 +r = b^2 \\
  & b^2 +r = c^2  \\ 
 &  c^2 +r = d^2  \\ 
\end{align}

where a,b,c,d,r $\in\mathbb{N}$

Hence, I found only triple succession.

For example:
1,5,7 because 
\begin{align}
\ & 1^2 +24 = 5^2 \\
  & 5^2 +24 = 7^2  \\ 
\end{align}
where the ratio is 24.

but I can't found a example with four number and the same common difference.
at worst. Could you demonstrate that nonexistent using reductio ad absurdum to this statement?.

Comment: It's usually called a common difference, not a ratio.

Comment: Ok, but I'm just learning English.
Thanks for your comment